# Packaging an exe installer with command line switches

Tags: windows, installation, exe, silent-installer

I need to create an exe installer that accepts command line switches.

I'd like to call my installer with some custom command line switches which it can then use accordingly. For example I'd like to be able to specify the destination for install using say something like `/S=\path\to\install` and other options like `\debug` for installing debug builds and so on.

I don't have prior experience with packaging software for Windows so I am a bit lost.
I've tried the iexpress installer that comes with windows, but I couldn't do what I was trying to with it. I'm also looking at http://www.advancedinstaller.com/ but that doesn't seem to have options for something like this either.

It is highly likely that either of these have the capability but I'm missing out on how to use it. But either way I would like to know how I can accomplish creating an exe installer with custom command line flags

Answer (score 0):

Start with WiX, http://wix.sourceforge.net/ , you need to learn it first, and then author your packaging using XML syntax, and then build your exe (self extractor) or MSI.

MSIInstaller.exe comes with many options, and it does help you pass command line arguments to your installer package, which is the out put of your WiX authoring.